# Why dumpbin does not show functions of some DLLs?

Tags: c#, dll, dumpbin

Here is a project [rawinput_latest.zip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput/rawinput_latest.zip)

Target framework: .Net 4

Output type: Class Library

Building Solution creates dll file.

Output of *dumpbin /exports RawInput.dll*

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Users\Qet\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\rawinput latest\RawInput\bin\x86\Debug\RawInput.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        6000 .text
```

Why dumpbin does not show functions of RawInput.dll?
Am I able to use the dll in another project?

Comment: C# cannot create unmanaged exports.  You need C++/CLI or an IL rewriter tool like Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports.  That project does use [DllImport], they don't appear either with the use the Dumpbin.exe /imports option.  Such functions are bound at runtime with LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag /EXPORTS is used to show exported functions in the PE. Regular C# methods won't be exported in the PE (and usually there is no need to). You still can reference the .NET assembly (dll) and use it from other **.net** projects.

If you want to use the functions from unamanaged code, then you may need to export export it. In that case, read [here](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports). If you don't need to export the functionality to other native apps, you probably won't need it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was what I was looking for

Comment: Link to /robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports is broken